# Mysql syntax error, 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use a conditional select in mysql, but i m getting a syntax error. Can you see an error?

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `proxies` 
    WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) and `status`='active'  and `PAYMENT`='sharedproxies' and `connections`<3;
    )
    THEN SELECT * FROM `proxies` WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) and `status`='active'  and `PAYMENT`='sharedproxies' and `connections`<3 limit 1;
ELSEIF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `proxies` 
    WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) and `status`='active'  and (`tier`='1' or `tier`='2') and `PAYMENT`='scanner' and `connections`<3
    )
    THEN SELECT * FROM `proxies` WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) and `status`='active'  and (`tier`='1' or `tier`='2') and `PAYMENT`='scanner' and `connections`<3 limit 1

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `proxies` WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 8640' at line 1
```

Comment: "` `last_used1/1` `"

Comment: 1) Please include the actual syntax error message.  2) I doubt `last_used1/1` is actually a column on your table.

Comment: In MySQL, you can only use the `if` statement in a code block -- a stored procedure,  function, or trigger.  Where is this code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL error message `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax` is always very clear. After the message '... for the right syntax to use near' it displays the part of the query that it could not understand.

In your case, the part MySQL does not understand starts at the very beginning of the query.
This is because of the "IF EXISTS (" (and "ELSEIF EXISTS" and "THEN") that is not valid MySQL syntax.

The easiest fix is to run the first query:

```
SELECT * FROM `proxies` WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) and `status`='active'  and `PAYMENT`='sharedproxies' and `connections`<3 limit 1
```

check in the client code if it returned something then, if did not, run the second query:

```
SELECT * FROM `proxies` WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) and `status`='active'  and (`tier`='1' or `tier`='2') and `PAYMENT`='scanner' and `connections`<3 limit 1
```

You can also do something like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM `proxies` WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) and `status`='active'  and `PAYMENT`='sharedproxies' and `connections`<3 limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `proxies` WHERE `last_used1/1`<(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400) and `status`='active'  and (`tier`='1' or `tier`='2') and `PAYMENT`='scanner' and `connections`<3 limit 1)
```

then, in the client code check the fields of the rows returned by the query to find out which row was returned by the first sub-query and which one by the second sub-query (assuming it returns 2 rows).

For more information about `UNION`/`UNION ALL` and how you can modify the query above to get what you need directly from `MySQL`, please read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Answer (score -1):

ELSEIF has to be: ELSE IF

I think that's the error. Can't you find it on www.google.com ?

Comment: The [`MySQL` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html) can be found on the MySQL website.